# React Router check condition before route change

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is it possible to check a condition before changing routes?

I have this function which listens to routes and logs everytime the app changes. I use it for debugging purposes but is it possible to check something like if localstorage contains a value, if not move to login page?

```js
useEffect(() => {
  history.listen(loc => {
    console.log(`route: ${loc.pathname}`);
  });
}, []);
```

Something like `if (loc.pathname !== '/login')` push to login. Within this `history.listen` function
I've tried using protected routes but I am getting an error where the graphql client loads the user in but if the token expires, it still loads the component. Then redirects.

Comment: Use [`<Prompt/>`](https://reactrouter.com/core/api/Prompt/message-func), specifically where you pass `message` a function.

Answer (score 0):

To change the current route, you can use the following line:

```js
window.location = '<YOUR_ROUTE>';
```

So for example, if you configured your login route to be like:

```js
<Route path="/login" component={Login} />
```

Then, in your useEffect function, you would just add the line

```js
useEffect(() => {
  history.listen(loc => {
    console.log(`route: ${loc.pathname}`);
    window.location = '/#/login';  // <-- this line here
  });
}, []);
```

And if you need to check a condition first before redirecting to the login route, you'll juste need to put the `window.location` line within your if, like:

```js
if (loc.pathname !== '/login') {
  window.location = '/#/login';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it using `history.push` method:

```
useEffect(() => {
  history.listen((loc) => {
    if (localStorage.getItem('someItem')) {
      history.push('/login');
    }
  });
}, []);
```

Read about that method and other available methods you can read in [documentation](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/history).